# Do some calulations of the values in two table and store it in third table mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

table1

```
| email           | result  |
----------------------------
| abc@gmail.com   |0.12      |
| dsv@gmail.com   |0.23      |
| rthgmail.com    | 0.45     |
| hfg@gmail.com   |0.56      |
| yyt@gmail.com   | 0.78     |
| hjg@gmail.com   | 0.35     |
```

table2

```
 | resource        |
 -------------------
 | 0.5             |
```

table3

```
| temp            |
-------------------
|NULL             |
```

Now I want addition of result and resource from table1 and table2 respectively for email abc@gmail.com and save the result in table3. I want to update the table3 every time.

I tried the following but its not working:

```
UPDATE table3 SET temp = table1.result + table2.resource WHERE email = 'abc@gmail.com'
```

How can I do it guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a sub query:

```
UPDATE Table3 t
SET t.temp = (SELECT s.result+p.resource
              FROM table1 s INNER JOIN table2 p
              ON(s.email = 'abc@gmail.com'))
```

If your Table3 doesn't have data yet:

```
INSERT INTO Table3 
(SELECT s.result+p.resource
 FROM table1 s INNER JOIN table2 p
  ON(s.email = 'abc@gmail.com'))
```

Comment: temp in Table3 is not getting updated. But if I run the SELECT s.result+p.resource
              FROM table1 s INNER JOIN table2 p
              ON(s.email = 'abc@gmail.com') separately then its working fine.

Comment: @MichaelCorleone Updated the answer, it happen because table3 doesn't have data yet, so it cannot be updated.. has to be inserted

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a curious request, but you want an `update` with `join`:

```
UPDATE table3 t3 CROSS JOIN
       table2 t2 CROSS JOIN JOIN
       (SELECT SUM(t1.result) FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.email = 'abc@gmail.com') t1
   SET t3.temp = t1.result + t2.resource;
```

Are you sure you don't really want an `insert` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have only one row of data in Table2 and Table3? In that case you could do:

```
UPDATE Table3 SET temp=SELECT SUM(result)+(SELECT MAX(resource) from table2) from table1 WHERE email = 'abc@gmail.com'
```

Any aggregate function (min, avg etc) other than MAX will do the job (if you really have only one row in table2). And and also identity columns would be better for table2 and table3.