# Do some calculations of the values from two table and store it in one of the table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

First Table Name: table1

```
| email           | value  |
----------------------------
| abc@gmail.com   |0.12      |
| dsv@gmail.com   |0.23      |
| rthgmail.com    | 0.45     |
| hfg@gmail.com   |0.56      |
| yyt@gmail.com   | 0.78     |
| hjg@gmail.com   | 0.35     |
```

Second Table Name: table2

```
| email           | result |
----------------------------
| abc@gmail.com   |0.3      |
| dsv@gmail.com   |0.6      |
| rthgmail.com    | 0.7     |
| hfg@gmail.com   |0.8      |
| yyt@gmail.com   | 0.1     |
| hjg@gmail.com   | 0.3     |
```

Now, I want to perform this mathematical operation

```
value(table1) = result(table2)+value(table1) /2
```

for email="abc@gmail.com"

I want to use the UPDATE query.

Thank you!!!

Comment: you should post your attempt as well

Comment: Your previous question has the information necessary to get this done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36065675/do-some-calulations-of-the-values-in-two-table-and-store-it-in-third-table-mysql What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `join` tables in update the same way you do in a `select`:

```
UPDATE table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.email=table2.email
SET table1.value = (table2.result + table1.value) / 2
WHERE table1.email = "abc@gmail.com"
```